# Wireless incredibly slow on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers

I have a 60Mbps internet, but on my laptop, very close to the access point, I only get 150kbps download speed.

It's not the access point. It's relatively new and, testing on my phone, the speed is normal.

Moreover, I tried changing the access point wireless protocol to 802.11g and 802.11b only, following some advice I saw in a forum, but it didn't help.

So it has to be the operating system, Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.

[image: Speed on the laptop. It shows 11Mbps, but the actual download speed only reaches 150kbps, even downloading from a server that does not limit speed.]

On the network manager it shows 11Mbps, but the actual download speed only reaches 150kbps, even downloading from a server that does not limit speed.

Comment: How close is "very close"?  You've got to keep in mind there's a dead zone of around six feet (vaguely two meters) around the AP.  If you support bgn, I see no reason not to leave n enabled

Comment: About 5 meters. But what puzzles me is that I'm using my smartphone exactly in the same place...

Comment: Do you have a machine on the LAN that you can test speeds against?  Are you on a crowded wireless channel?  Your laptop use 802.11b, but your phone probably uses 802.11g or n.  You might try changing wireless channels — in my experience, if you are on network with both kinds of devices, any channel other than 1 results in abysmal performance of b devices

Comment: It's an inspiron 14 n4050, it has b/g/n, maybe the correct driver is missing, idk, but in this case I'm done, dell doesn't support linux

Comment: There are two possible wireless cards in an Inspiron 14 n4050.  The DW1701 is the very poorly supported BCM4313 Broadcom card.  DW1702 is a much better-supported AR9285 Atheros card.  Do you know which you have?

Comment: Mine is a AR9285 :)

Comment: You might create `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` containing `options ath9k nohwcrypt=1` and another just like it but replacing `ath9k` everywhere by `ath9k_htc`. Some users have reported problems with hardware crypto causing terrible speeds on these cards

Comment: I did it exactly like you told me but the problem persists :((

Comment: I don't think you mentioned earlier; what channel is your router set to broadcast on? If it isn't 1, set it to 1.  If at all possible, I would also suggest trying to connect to a different AP somewhere, as distance and interference make a huge difference with WiFi. I'm to the point where the only things not connected by Ethernet are my phones

Comment: Still nothing :(((

Comment: Any strangeness in `dmesg`?  Also, to be absolutely sure it isn't the internet itself being in the way, run this if you can: `printf '%s\n' 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' '' | cat - <(od -t x1 $(which vim)) | nc -l -p 1500` on your laptop, then connect to `http://ip.of.the.laptop:1500` with your phone or other device, and watch the network usage. Does that exhibit the same problem?  This makes a one-time HTTP server that exclusively serves a hexdump of `vim`, which can be used to measure connection speeds without involving much else

Comment: I know it's lazy, but I went and bought 15 meters of Ethernet cable this afternoon. Done. haha thanks for all your help :)